# Display nested headers dynamically in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to create a nested set of headers in a Tablix in SSRS.

Such that in the first level grouping (Source), it shows a header of Count and a value for the total count of that group (source).

If you expand out the Source group, it would display the values inside the group, with a header that only displays when you expand the group?

I cant seem to nest the groups correctly. Do i need to use additional Total rows within the group?

[image: Example of how headers should look]

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, the easiest way is to build the report fully expanded with all the detail (and the totals you want to see when expanded).

Right-Click the row header, choose properties and set the row visibility for the rows you want to hide to hidden
Finally, in the same dialog, set the 'Display can be toggled by this report item' to the textbox you want to click when expanding the group.